# Running Visual Studio 2013 with Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

How can I run Visual Studio 2013 with Windows 8.1? As I get that the visual studio is not compatible with Windows 8.1?

This is what I get:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you running?  That should work fine.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with `SnippingTool.exe` (included with windows in the System32 folder) and post a image of the error message?

Comment: Works on my machine. I am running VS2013 Ultimate on a Windows 8.1 (virtual) machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message says exactly what is wrong:

"This version of Visual Studio is not compatible with **pre-release** versions of Windows 8.1".

Update your Windows 8.1 to the RTM version and then it should work.